# Filter the JSON - Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
{"data": [
  {
    "client": {
      "name": "TEST NAME",
      "client_id": "id_client_boU6cpFX55vkLCXt52TSVB"
    },
    "Pay_list": [
      {
        "pay_id": "id_pay_aAW6mEvsCpBVT4aASDERTY"
      },
      {
        "pay_id": "id_pay_aAW6mEvsCpBVT4aTDgVCSD"
      }
    ],
    "company": {
      "name": "ABCD",
      "ID": "1234"
    }
  },
  {
    "client": {
      "name": "TEST NAME",
      "client_id": "id_client_boU6cpFX55vkLCXt52TSVB"
    },
    "Pay_list": [
      {
        "pay_id": "id_pay_aAW6mEvsCpBVT4aASQQQW"
      },
      {
        "pay_id": "id_pay_aAW6mEvsCpBVT4aTDDFGE"
      },
      {
        "pay_id": "id_pay_aAW6mEvsCpBVT4aTDgVDFE"
      }
    ],
    "company": {
      "name": "fBfD",
      "ID": "5214"
    }
  },
]
}
```

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkTcG.png)

I need to filter this JSON and get the company name.

```
this.Detail = result.data.filter(item => item.client.client_id== this.client_client_id && item.Pay_list.pay_id == this.PayId);
```

I have tried the above code and it trow the error because Pay_list is an array.

How can I filter the above JSON? Please assist me.

Comment: you'll need to use an inner `item.Pay_list.some(x => x.pay_id == whatever)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this snippet instead. Have attached a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-extract-array-filter?file=src/app/app.component.html)** for your reference :

**Possible variables needed for filter:**

```
const clientId = "id_client_boU6cpFX55vkLCXt52TSVB";
const payId = "id_pay_aAW6mEvsCpBVT4aASDERTY";
```

**Code**

```
const result = response
  .data
  .filter(({ client: { client_id }, Pay_list }) => client_id === clientId && Pay_list.some(pay => pay.pay_id === payId))[0]
  .company
  .name;
```

**Result:**

```
ABCD
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
const client_id = 'id_client_boU6cpFX55vkLCXt52TSVB';
const pay_id = 'id_pay_aAW6mEvsCpBVT4aASQQQW';

const filtered = result.data.filter((item) => {
  if (item.client.client_id !== client_id) return false;
  if (item.Pay_list.map(({ pay_id }) => pay_id).includes(pay_id)) return false;
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const client_id = 'id_client_boU6cpFX55vkLCXt52TSVB';
const pay_id = 'id_pay_aAW6mEvsCpBVT4aASQQQW';

const result = response
  .data
  .filter(({ client: { client_id }, Pay_list }) => client_id === clientId && Pay_list.some(pay => pay.pay_id === payId))[0]
  .company
  .name;
```